# looping in address array?

Tags: java, error-handling, imap

I am a beginner in java and I am trying to loop the address array(address[]) but I don't know the size of array and is not able to check the end point of array.
this is my code:

```
int j=0;
              System.out.println(j);
              while(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)[j]!=null)
             {cc =cc.concat(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)[j].toString());
             cc =cc.concat(",");
             j++;
             System.out.println(j);}  

          }
```

basically msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC) is array of type address and when irun this I get error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at test2.main(test2.java:135)
```

Comment: you can't do `myarray[j]` if `j` is out of your array's bounds, as it returns the exception you got. However, you can check an array's length using `myarray.length`. This works with any array, and allows you to iterate easily through the array with a `for` loop, like this `for (int j=0; j<myarray.length;j++){myarray[j]=...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) there is the

> `public final` field `length` -

So, that should be something like -

```
int j=0;
while(j < msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC).length)
{
  System.out.println(j);
  cc = cc.concat(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)[j].toString());
  cc = cc.concat(",");
  j++;
}
```

Comment: The new for() style makes it even shorter: for(Address a : msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)) System.out.println(a);

Comment: @arnt While the [For-Each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop is nice it would lose the log of `j`; also, it isn't exactly new anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you would look at this [tutorial](http://codingbat.com/doc/java-array-loops.html) you will see that there is a variable called `length` that holds the size of an array. And that a for-loop is better suited for what you want to achive

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //do stuff with array[i]
}
```

Comment: Not `.length()` just `.length` in the case of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC).length, which gives the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int j=0;
System.out.println(j);
while(j < msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC).length){
      cc =cc.concat(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)[j].toString());
      cc =cc.concat(",");
      j++;
      System.out.println(j);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to understand here is that you always know the size of an array in Java, and you can access it using the array's *length* attribute, e.g. `myArray.length`. Beyond that there are a couple of areas where your approach could be improved:

- You are getting the array every time around the `while` loop, which might work fine but is unnecessary work. Just grab the array once and then loop over its content.
- If your `cc` variable is a `String` then be aware that strings are immutable, which means that every time you call `concat` on it you are creating a new `String` object. This is not a very efficient way of dynamically building up a String using a loop. Good practice would be to use a `StringBuilder` (which is mutable) to build up the final text, then convert it to a `String` when you're done.

Your code might look something like this:

```
StringBuilder recipients = new StringBuilder();
Address[] ccs = msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
for (int i = 0; i < ccs.length; i++)
{
  if (i > 0) recipients.append(",");
  recipients.append(ccs[i]);
}

String result = recipients.toString();
```